# How do I fix this jquery security alert: "Your app contains one or more libraries with known security issues"

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, zurb-foundation

In my Play Developer console I see the following message for several Apache Cordova apps I have in my store:

> Security alert
>
> Your app contains one or more libraries with known
> security issues. Please see this Google Help Center article for
> details. Vulnerable JavaScript libraries:
>
> /javascripts/jquery 1.8.2
>
> SNYK-npm:jquery:20110606
>
> SNYK-npm:jquery:20150627
>
> SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006

The developer tools in Chrome gives details on the problem. The **jquery.js** and **jquery.foundation.topbar.js** files are the culprit:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).die is not a function TypeError: $(...).die is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///Users.../www/javascripts/jquery.foundation.topbar.js:45:40)
    at Function.each (file:///Users/.../www/javascripts/jquery.js:2:2777)
    at k.fn.init.each (file:///Users/.../www/javascripts/jquery.js:2:1419)
    at k.fn.init.init (file:///Users/.../www/javascripts/jquery.foundation.topbar.js:21:21)
    at k.fn.init.$.fn.foundationTopBar (file:///Users/.../www/javascripts/jquery.foundation.topbar.js:152:27)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///Users/.../www/javascripts/app.js:12:44)
    at e (file:///Users/.../www/javascripts/jquery.js:2:29453)
    at t (file:///Users/.../www/javascripts/jquery.js:2:29755) undefined
```

I overwrote the /javascripts/jquery.js v1.8.2 code with with jquery 3.4.1 (testing both full and slim build versions) -- and now my 2010 Zurb Foundation topbar functionality (used across the top as navigation for narrow screens) doesn't work. (The wide screen left nav list does work.)

When I went to download the Foundation 6 pared-down version, selecting just the topbar functionality, there was no topbar file included with the download. Looks like it'll be a messy update.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

New: Based on the following, there is no backwards compatibility: https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/44018-documentation-for-upgrade-from-foundation-5-to-6

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?